# Google map con estilo no marca el sitio indicado

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Mi mapa de Google Maps no señala al sitio que le indico con su típica flecha roja. ¿Qué puedo hacer para que aparezca?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Styled Maps - Night Mode</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      function initMap() {
        // Styles a map in night mode.
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: 40.4610378, lng: -3.6926671},
          zoom: 12,
          styles: [
              {
                "elementType": "geometry",
                "stylers": [
                  {
                    "color": "#212121"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "elementType": "labels.icon",
                "stylers": [
                  {
                    "visibility": "off"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                "stylers": [
                  {
                    "color": "#7a7a7a"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
                "stylers": [
                  {
                    "color": "#212121"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "featureType": "administrative",
                "elementType": "geometry",
                "stylers": [
                  {
                    "color": "#757575"
                  },
                  {
                    "visibility": "off"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "featureType": "administrative.country",
                "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                "stylers": [
                  {
                    "color": "#9e9e9e"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
                "stylers": [
                  {
                    "visibility": "off"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "featureType": "administrative.locality",
                "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                "stylers": [
                  {
                    "color": "#bdbdbd"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "featureType": "poi",
                "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                "stylers": [
                  {
                    "color": "#757575"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "featureType": "poi.park",
                "elementType": "geometry",
                "stylers": [
                  {
                    "color": "#181818"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "featureType": "poi.park",
                "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                "stylers": [
                  {
                    "color": "#616161"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "featureType": "poi.park",
                "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
                "stylers": [
                  {
                    "color": "#1b1b1b"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "featureType": "road",
                "elementType": "geometry.fill",
                "stylers": [
                  {
                    "color": "#2c2c2c"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "featureType": "road",
                "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                "stylers": [
                  {
                    "color": "#8a8a8a"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "featureType": "road.arterial",
                "elementType": "geometry",
                "stylers": [
                  {
                    "color": "#373737"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "featureType": "road.highway",
                "elementType": "geometry",
                "stylers": [
                  {
                    "color": "#3c3c3c"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "featureType": "road.highway.controlled_access",
                "elementType": "geometry",
                "stylers": [
                  {
                    "color": "#4e4e4e"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "featureType": "road.local",
                "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                "stylers": [
                  {
                    "color": "#616161"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "featureType": "transit",
                "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                "stylers": [
                  {
                    "color": "#757575"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "featureType": "water",
                "elementType": "geometry",
                "stylers": [
                  {
                    "color": "#171717"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "featureType": "water",
                "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                "stylers": [
                  {
                    "color": "#3d3d3d"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCgwNQv5F2fD6WzRtbjE_4T-wvyQDZPxyg&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes crear un marker, como lo explica la [documentacion](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-labels?hl=es-419) de google maps
con el comando :

```
new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location, //debes elegir las coordenadas
            map: map  // en que mapa lo quieres ver
```

En ejemplo lo que quieres realizar, se realizo en base al ejemplo de google map para que puedas crear un archivo **`js`** con las funcionalidades comunes:

```js
function initMap() {
        // Styles a map in night mode.
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: 40.4610378, lng: -3.6926671},
          zoom: 12,
          styles: [
              {
                "elementType": "geometry",
                "stylers": [
                  {
                    "color": "#212121"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "elementType": "labels.icon",
                "stylers": [
                  {
                    "visibility": "off"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                "stylers": [
                  {
                    "color": "#7a7a7a"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
                "stylers": [
                  {
                    "color": "#212121"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "featureType": "administrative",
                "elementType": "geometry",
                "stylers": [
                  {
                    "color": "#757575"
                  },
                  {
                    "visibility": "off"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "featureType": "administrative.country",
                "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                "stylers": [
                  {
                    "color": "#9e9e9e"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
                "stylers": [
                  {
                    "visibility": "off"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "featureType": "administrative.locality",
                "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                "stylers": [
                  {
                    "color": "#bdbdbd"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "featureType": "poi",
                "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                "stylers": [
                  {
                    "color": "#757575"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "featureType": "poi.park",
                "elementType": "geometry",
                "stylers": [
                  {
                    "color": "#181818"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "featureType": "poi.park",
                "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                "stylers": [
                  {
                    "color": "#616161"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "featureType": "poi.park",
                "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
                "stylers": [
                  {
                    "color": "#1b1b1b"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "featureType": "road",
                "elementType": "geometry.fill",
                "stylers": [
                  {
                    "color": "#2c2c2c"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "featureType": "road",
                "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                "stylers": [
                  {
                    "color": "#8a8a8a"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "featureType": "road.arterial",
                "elementType": "geometry",
                "stylers": [
                  {
                    "color": "#373737"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "featureType": "road.highway",
                "elementType": "geometry",
                "stylers": [
                  {
                    "color": "#3c3c3c"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "featureType": "road.highway.controlled_access",
                "elementType": "geometry",
                "stylers": [
                  {
                    "color": "#4e4e4e"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "featureType": "road.local",
                "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                "stylers": [
                  {
                    "color": "#616161"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "featureType": "transit",
                "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                "stylers": [
                  {
                    "color": "#757575"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "featureType": "water",
                "elementType": "geometry",
                "stylers": [
                  {
                    "color": "#171717"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "featureType": "water",
                "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                "stylers": [
                  {
                    "color": "#3d3d3d"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
        });
        function addMarker(location, map) {
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            map: map
        });
      }
        addMarker({lat: 40.4610378, lng: -3.6926671}, map);
      }
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCgwNQv5F2fD6WzRtbjE_4T-wvyQDZPxyg&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```